# Suddenly cannot open local .py files (Python source files) as plain text in Firefox

Tags: firefox, python

Up until a few days ago, I could click a link to a locally stored .py file and Firefox would display it as a plain text file. This is what I want; e.g., it’s a way for me to organize notes, view examples I’ve created in the past, and like that.

Now when I click such a link, Firefox pops up a window asking me if I want to “Open with …” or “Save file”.

I installed Python 3.9.6 a few days ago, so I wondered if that was a coincidence. I don’t think it is, because I just went to another machine, where clicking a link to a .py file worked as desired, updated the Python on that machine, and now I’m seeing the same (unwanted) behavior.  Therefore, I believe something might be going on with the Python installation process.  However, it also seems to me like this should be something that I could fix in Firefox's settings somewhere.

I've tried a bunch of stuff suggested on Mozilla's pages, including deleting the handlers.json file in my Profile folder, running a full Refresh, and creating a new profile.  None of these got me back to the old behavior.  General Googling has not helped; most of the results are out of date, and/or advise installation of a Firefox extension (no longer checked for security holes by Mozilla).

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

P.S.  I've got a similar question posted on support.mozilla.org and discuss.python.org, and will update if I get any answers from either of those.

P.P.S.  [ETA] Running on Windows 10 Pro, Firefox v90.0.2.

Comment: Start > Choose a default app for each type of file > Scroll to .py and set firefox as the default app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but .py (or PY) does not appear in the list of possible file types in settings.  Also, note what I said above about trying to set Firefox as the default app to open a .py file, from the pop-up window: it doesn't work, it just keeps popping up the same window in another new tab.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You were talking about the Windows associations.  No, I don't want to do that, because when I'm not in the browser, I want Python to run the .py files.

Comment: *"I could click a link to a locally stored `.py` file"* - It might be helpful to specify what link(s) you were actually clicking to get this behavior.

Comment: Here is an example.  I have files called "cheatsheet.html," which has got a dozen or so things that I had to write down to remember, back a few months ago.  Typically, each of the items has a very quick bit of code, and then says something like this: 
<p>Example: <a href="file:///c:/bjk/Dropbox/notes/python/DCP/DCP0138/v02.py">DCP0138/v02.py</a></p>  Note that the same problem (now) occurs if I open up a directory listing from within Firefox; e.g., "file:///c:/bjk/Dropbox/notes/python/cheatsheet/demos/" and then click a link to a .py file from there.

Comment: I mean, really, it's about as plain-vanilla an HTML file as you could imagine.  Just something quick and dirty that lets me see things in one place, where I have the ability to do a basic text search and where I can refer to external files, for some of my longwindedness, instead of explicitly including all of it.

Answer (score 2):

Not that many people seem to care, but just in case, for someone in the future …

When I didn’t find a solution to the above, I decided the least painful way to deal with the problem was to go into Settings > Applications in Firefox, and associate PY files with Emacs. So, now when I click a link to one of my local `.py` files, an Emacs window pops up, with that file in it.

Due to a typo a couple of days ago, I discovered another workaround: in the URL for the file, just append a dot, and then the proper file will open in the browser, as a plain text file, which is all I ever wanted. (Well, not *all*.) That is, this line in an HTML file will cause the file to open in a pop-up Emacs window …

`<a href="file:///c:/some-dir/example.py">example.py</a>`

… but this will open the same file, right in the browser (note the dot after the .py extension):

`<a href="file:///c:/some-dir/example.py">example.py.</a>`